# Json Binary needs to convert into blob data as image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I am calling an api where i am getting multiple binary data as json. later i want to convert binary data into blob image.

[api response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2lZj.png)

here i am create image src from response. But image is not showing with this src

```
const imageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data[0].blob))

<img src={imageSrc} />
```

Comment: [
    {
        blob: "b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x
        file: "profile_c46c4978-a3f6-4f8a-95e0-b800a6a10b12"
        type: "image"
    },
    {
        blob: "b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x
        file: "profile_c46c4978-a3f6-4f8a-95e0-b800a6a10b12"
        type: "image"
    }

]

each blob value i wan to create image src link

Comment: `imageAsUrl` !== `imageSrc` for one thing.

Comment: @Andy variable was corrected but still same issue

Comment: Does your API provide a documentation regarding the encoding they use?  They seem to encode only certain characters to hex and wrap it in some "command" (`b'`?) So [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7kruybh1/) should do with the small excerpt you did show, but without seeing the exact encoding they used, impossible to say it will work correctly or not.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the `Blob` Class as `fetch` response already returns Blob

Try doing this

```js
const imageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data[0].blob)
<img src={imageSrc} />
```